# Windows update crashed virtualization (homestead vagrant box)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, amd-processor, windows-update

After new Windows 10 (64-bit) update, my vagrant box isn't working anymore. I have checked BIOS and virtualization is still enabled (I have AMD processor). I have updated vagrant box to Laravel 5, but nothing changed.

When trying to run `vagrant up` I get this:

[image]

And when I go and manually open vagrant box (Oracle VM VirtualBox) I get this:

[image]

Under `Settings->System` my `Acceleration` tab is greyed out

Comment: did you try to run virtualbox as administrator?

Comment: Yes, no help. It worked fine before the update without the need to run it as admin